# Value of datetime input field can not pass validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have this input field for picking date and time

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="game-date-time-text" name="game_date_time">
```

And I am trying to format it with below rule

```
'game_date_time' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-dTH:i'
```

When I look at the value of this field in my request, an example value looks like this

> 2001-03-13T13:30

I tried arious types of datetime formats including the one above but my input value can not pass validation. What is the problem here ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and it worked.

```
'game_date_time' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place `data_format` rule inside double quotes.

`'game_date_time' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-dH:i"'`

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-date-format

Comment: `Y-m-dH:i` not `Y-m-dTH:i` did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly as in your answer.

Comment: In your 'config/app.php` you will find `'timezone' =>` What is it set to? `UTC`? Change it to your zone format. Example `America/Chicago` then clear your cache `php artisan config:cache` `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'game_date_time' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-dTH:i"'
```

date_format format must be in inside double quotes `""`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got the solution. At first, make sure your date column is in `DATETIME` type.  Assuming your date_time rules like this in the model:

```
public static $date_rules = [
    'game_date_time' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-dTH:i'
];
```

And in your controller the method you are getting the date_time value:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function postDate(Request $request, Role $role){

    $datevalidator = Validator::make($request->all(), YourModel::$date_rules);
    if ($datevalidator->fails()){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($datevalidator)->withInput();
    }// this 'if' checks the validation.
    $game_date_time=$request->get('game_date_time');
    return $game_date_time;
}
```

Hope this helps.